# JavaScript Mapeando troca de atributos

Tags: javascript, html5, javascript-eventos

Tenho uma tag que preciso saquando quando é feita a troca do atributo para fazer uma ação em cima dessa troca usando `JavaScript`.

Ex:

```html
<span attr="doSomething"></span>
```

Ao trocar o atributo `attr` quero que execute algum evento que será passado dentro de `attr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os elementos HTML não possuem um evento para a troca de atributos, mas isso pode ser feito usando `MutationObserver`, uma classe que verifica modificações feitas nos objetos.

```html
<span id="test" attr="doSomething"></span>
```

```js
var element = document.querySelector('#test');
var mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(function(mutations){
  // mutations é uma lista das alteração que foram feitas na tag
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation){
    if(mutation.type === 'attributes'){
      console.log('Ouve mudança de atributo');
    }
  });
});

mutationObserver.observer(element, {attributes: true});

var interval = setInterval(function(){
  element.setAttribute('attr', 'doAnything');
  clearInterval(interval);
},1000);
```